# how to use convolutional neural network for non-image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I search a lot but I cannot find anything to show that how can I generate data for continuous dataset such as [breastCancer](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+(original))? All documents are about images or text classifications. 
Can you please help me construct neural network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CNNs are useful for datasets where the features have strong temporal or spatial correlation. For instance, in the case of images, the value of a pixel is highly correlated to the neighboring pixels. If you randomly permute the pixels, then this correlation goes away, and convolution no longer makes sense.

For the breast cancer dataset, you have only 10 attributes which are not spatially correlated in this way. Unlike the previous image example, you can randomly permute these 10 features and no information is lost. Therefore, CNNs are not directly useful for this problem domain.